# Properly align text and equation (single line, three column mixed text and equation)

Tags: align, amsmath

I have what feels like an very odd problem.

My goal is to simply create a simple single line equation of the following form:

```
(equation) (text) (equation)
```

I tried several approaches to achieve this with the align environment, provided by the amsmath package.

My first approach looked something like this:

```
\begin{align}
  a &= b & \text{or} & a &= b 
\end{align}
```

However it returns:

[image: latex_misalignment]

If I replace the text in the middle this problem becomes easily solvable by just putting an extra '&' in its middle. Also having multiple lines seem to solve it. Yet I couldn't find a way to achieve this in this very setting. Any Ideas?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Try using the `aligned` environment instead of `align`. Note that it has to be in mathmode: `\[ \begin{aligned}\end{aligned} \]`

Comment: `align`is for alignment, while you say you want to create a single line. What about simple and plain `\[ a=b \qquad\text{or}\qquad a=b\]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you missed is that you need 5 `&` for 3 alignment points: each column of alignment, except the first, requires one `&` to start a new column, and another `&`  to mark the alignment point inside that column:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document} %

\begin{align}
  a &= b & & \text{or} & a &= b
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the following setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\text' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 a = b  \qquad \text{or} \qquad  c = d
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If `\qquad` doesn't provide enough horizontal separation, give `\qquad\quad` or `\qquad\qquad` a try.

If you don't need the equation to be numbered, replace `equation` with `equation*`.

Note that there's little point in deploying the heavy-duty machinery of the `align` environment, since no alignment across rows is going to be performed, right?